# Supporting Copy/Paste on the web

Tags: mobile-web, web, copy-paste

Do you have a recommendation on how it would be possible to help people to copy and paste data to their clipboard from a website?

Would love to allow users to copy a coupon code from the web, but especially on mobile it seems to be a cumbersome effort to select and copy text.
Cheers

Comment: This is platform-dependent, surely. Both iOS and Windows Phone make it reasonably easy. What mobile platform are you thinking of?

Comment: Simply add "copy" next to text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy / paste is the clunkiest thing when it comes to mobile. You can at least ease the pain of copying by embedding the functionality into a one-tap button and have that perform the copying part for you.

This example is from addthis.com. Clicking on "Grab It" automatically copies the code in the box.

[image: example]

This solution is also super convenient for users on desktop as well.

Comment: Love the one-tap button approach, but are you aware of any examples that would work on a mobile browser? From my understanding, this approach requires Flash :-( Checking addthis.com with a mobile browser, the "grab it" button becomes a "Send to email" button. Though I'm not sure whether this is due to technical limitation or just for convenience.

Comment: I don't know if there is a technical limitation. You'd probably get a more precise answer in a developer forum. They'd be able to provide specs and a solid yes/no regarding feasibility.